# Delphi: TPersistent and csDesigning State

Tags: delphi, tpersistent

How can I detect `TPersistent` class is in csDesigning State?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Seeing your recent questions, it appears you've been trying to create a thread which shows a form during a long query process. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't a "Help me accomplish my project" or "Write my code for me" or "suggest ideas for me" kind of site. The design and coding is entirely up to you, and you must only ask specific questions here when you get stuck on one particular piece.

Comment: I can advise though that combining VCL and Threads is always a tricky subject. All UI interaction should be 100% implemented in your main thread, and your own threads must be independent of the main thread. For example, your thread should never try to do something like `Form1.Property := Value;`. It should trigger an event of some sort to notify the main thread that it needs to do so. That's the general concept of multi-threaded applications.

Comment: Thank you Jerry and I Realized

Comment: Multi-threaded applications is very hard to understand, but I'm sure do it in future...

Comment: Can you introduce me to make a complete reference about that?

Comment: Please note: The proposed duplicate question was only "allowed" because it was 4 years ago, back when Stack Overflow allowed such questions, because the community was still building. However lately, these questions become frowned upon (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: @Mohammadreza Stack Overflow also isn't a site to recommend tools, libraries, or do research for you. You must make your best effort to do your project. We're here to help you when you get stuck on something and can't find the right solution to solve it. Questions are expected to show research effort and be useful to others. Please hover your mouse over the up-vote and down-vote arrows on your question, and read the tool-tips which pop up. This is how people vote on the integrity of your question.

Comment: I ask this question before I went to the site 'What's the easiest way to write a please wait screen with Delphi?' but I didn't answer.

Comment: Put the database code in the thread

Comment: @Mohammadreza, please start reading [here](http://thaddy.co.uk/threads/)

Comment: You can't, TPersistent does not have design support or states. Please do not modify a question to ask a different one. Instead ask a new question.

Comment: My account was banned and can't ask new question.

Comment: Is there any way to use csDesigning State in the class?

Comment: @Mohammad - Perhaps there's a reason for that. I guess the ban is temporary. Anyway, test your persistent if it is a component and then typecast it.

Comment: Before it, I try typecast but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a database, a thread can be helpful if you wish for a rich user experience. The thread should be responsible for the sole purpose of performing lengthy tasks, in your case, a database query which takes time to complete.

In order to accomplish any temporary *responsive* form which displays during such a long database query, you must perform all of your GUI updates within the main thread, using `Synchronize` inside your thread to instruct your main thread to do so. There are many varieties of ways to do this, but I won't get into that detail.

VCL is a complicated library, and isn't thread-safe. You must thread-protect all interaction with anything and everything that can be accessed by multiple threads - and each of those threads must be designed to respect whatever protection mechanism you implement. However, the VCL has no concept of your thread protection, and has a mind of its own. Therefore, you must always respect the `Synchronize` procedure for your thread to send some sort of instruction to your main thread.

In your case, I would create two synchronized procedures: `StartProcess` and `StopProcess`. These procedures are called for example `Synchronize(StartProcess);` which would in turn trigger an event to notify the main thread that a process has started - and thus the main thread should show your temporary window alerting of a lengthy process. Synchronize the `StopProcess` event when the query is done.

As far as the actual window which you wish to display, that is entirely up to you, although they usually have a repetitive animation to illustrate a lengthy process.